# Testing Observable epic which invokes other epic

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I am trying to test a Redux Observable epic which dispatches an action to invoke an other epic. Somehow the invoked epic is not called.

Lets say my epics looks like this;

```
const getJwtEpic = (action$, store, { api }) =>
  action$.ofType('GET_JWT_REQUEST')
    .switchMap(() => api.getJWT()
      .map(response => {
        if (response.errorCode > 0) {
          return {
            type: 'GET_JWT_FAILURE',
            error: { code: response.errorCode, message: response.errorMessage },
          };
        }

        return {
          type: 'GET_JWT_SUCCESS',
          idToken: response.id_token,
        };
      })
    );

const bootstrapEpic = (action$, store, { api }) =>
  action$.ofType('BOOTSTRAP')
    .switchMap(() =>
      action$.filter(({ type }) => ['GET_JWT_SUCCESS', 'GET_JWT_FAILURE'].indexOf(type) !== -1)
        .take(1)
        .mergeMap(action => {
          if (action.type === 'GET_JWT_FAILURE') {
            return Observable.of({ type: 'BOOTSTRAP_FAILURE' });
          }

          return api.getProfileInfo()
            .map(({ profile }) => ({
              type: 'BOOTSTRAP_SUCCESS', profile,
            }));
        })
        .startWith({ type: 'GET_JWT_REQUEST' })
    );
```

When I try to test the `bootstrapEpic` in Jest with the following code;

```
const response = {};

const api = { getJWT: jest.fn() };
api.getJWT.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(response));

const action$ = ActionsObservable.of(actions.bootstrap());
const epic$ = epics.bootstrapEpic(action$, null, { api });

const result = await epic$.toArray().toPromise();
console.log(result);
```

The `console.log` call gives me the following output;

```
[ { type: 'GET_JWT_REQUEST' } ]
```

Somehow the `getJwtEpic` isn't called at all. I guess it has something to do with the `action$` observable not dispatching the `GET_JWT_REQUEST` action but I can't figure out why. All help is so welcome!

Comment: What is the source for rehydrateEpic?

Comment: That was a small typo, excuse me! I was trying to call the `bootstrapEpic` there.

Comment: You aren't calling `getJwtEpic` anywhere? Why do you think that it would be called? The `result` variable you have (the stream before you call `toPromise` on it) is the output of the `bootstrapEpic`, which is to be expected. I don't understand what you want to see, sorry.

Comment: Eventually I want to have an array like this;

     ['GET_JWT_REQUEST', 'GET_JWT_SUCCESS', 'BOOTSTRAP_SUCCESS']

Comment: So the result of both epics, but I can't figure out how to get the result of the epics combined.

Comment: Ah, you may be looking to combine the two epics, similar to how you would in your app proper, using [`combineEpics`](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/api/combineEpics.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `actions.rehydrate()` returns an action of type `BOOTSTRAP` and the `gigya` stuff is a typo,

`getJwtEpic` isn't called because you didn't call it yourself  When you test epics by manually calling them, then it's just a function which returns an Observable, without any knowledge of the middleware or anything else. The plumbing that connects `getJwtEpic` as part of the root epic, and provides it with `(action$, store)` is part of the middleware, which you're not using in your test.

This is the right approach, testing them in isolation, without redux/middleware.  So you test each epic individually, by providing it actions and dependencies, then asserting on the actions it emits and the dependencies it calls.

You'll test the success path something like this:

```
const api = {
  getProfileInfo: () => Observable.of({ profile: 'mock profile' })
};
const action$ = ActionsObservable.of(
  actions.rehydrate(),
  { type: 'GET_JWT_SUCCESS', idToken: 'mock token' }
);

const epic$ = epics.bootstrapEpic(action$, null, { api });

const result = await epic$.toArray().toPromise();

expect(result).toEqual([
  { type: 'GET_JWT_REQUEST' },
  { type: 'BOOTSTRAP_SUCCESS', profile: 'mock profile' }
]);
```

Then you'll test the failure path in another test by doing the same thing except giving it `GET_JWT_FAILURE` instead of `GET_JWT_SUCCESS`. You can then test `getJwtEpic` separately as well.

---

btw, `ofType` accepts any number of types, so you can just do `action$.ofType('GET_JWT_SUCCESS', 'GET_JWT_FAILURE')`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I've stared to long to my code to missed those typos, fixed them in the question. I'll try it in my code to check if I understand it now.

Comment: Wow I finally get my head around testing nested epics! I took some paradigma change I guess haha

Comment: yay! so glad this helped.